# Getting undefined reference after removing address sanitizer

Tags: c, makefile, shared-libraries

I am a newbie to c and I have trouble building a toy shared library in Linux.

the shared library works fine when I am adding `-fsanitize=address` flag to my makefile, but I would get undefined error after removing the sanitizer.

My error message:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccjVftXd.o: in function `main':
main.c:(.text+0x9): undefined reference to `foo'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [makefile:31: main] Error 1
```

The toy example looks like:

```c
// Path:foo.c
int foo(void) {
    return 1;
}
```

```c
// Path:main.c
extern int foo(void);

int main(void) {
return foo();
}
```

```
# my makefile
# Compiler options
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -Wall -fPIC

# Sanitizer
# this is commented and would get the error.
# CFLAGS += -fsanitize=address

# Target library
# add your lib path here
LIB_ROOT = ...
LIBRARY = $(LIB_ROOT)/libfoo.so

# Source files
SRCS = foo.c

# Object files
OBJS = $(SRCS:.c=.o)

# Default target
all: $(LIBRARY) main

# Compile source files into object files
%.o: %.c
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $\< -o $@

# Link object files into shared library
$(LIBRARY): $(OBJS)
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -shared $^ -o $@

# Compile main.c using the library
main: main.c $(LIBRARY)
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -L$(LIB_ROOT) -lfoo main.c -o main

# Clean build artifacts
clean:
rm -f $(OBJS) $(LIBRARY) main
```

My build log:

```
 >>> make
gcc -Wall -fPIC -c foo.c -o foo.o
gcc -Wall -fPIC -shared foo.o -o /my/path/libfoo.so
gcc -Wall -fPIC -L/my/path/lib -lfoo main.c -o main
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccTbYeMl.o: in function `main':
main.c:(.text+0x9): undefined reference to `foo'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [makefile:31: main] Error 1
```

The shared library information:

`$ nm -D /my/lib/path/libfoo.so`

```
                 w __cxa_finalize
00000000000010f9 T foo
                 w __gmon_start__
                 w _ITM_deregisterTMCloneTable
                 w _ITM_registerTMCloneTable
```

My operating system:
`Ubuntu 20.04 LTS`

Comment: Please show the *full* and *complete* build-log, including the actual command used.

Comment: But in your case it's rather simple to guess: The order of libraries and source/object files when building. You need to pass libraries *after* the source and object files when linking.

Comment: Sorry I don't quite get what you mean: If it was the matter the order, using `-fsanitize=address` should still fail, right...? (build log updated)

Comment: The command `gcc -Wall -fPIC -L/my/path/lib -lfoo main.c -o main` needs to be `gcc -Wall -fPIC main.c -o main -L/my/path/lib -lfoo`

Comment: Yes it worked! Thanks dude. But I still don't understand why using `-fsanitize=address` could also make it work : (

Comment: As for why it supposedly work with the sanitizer, perhaps it causes the driver-program `gcc` to rearrange library order?

Comment: Not quite sure but I supposed you are right. I found adding any sanitizer works. Perhaps the sanitizers are doing me a favor.

Comment: I would guess the sanitizer is instrumenting the function and it is marked as used even when the code hasn't used it yet or possibly doesn't use it. It's no favor if your build breaks when you turn it off, it's a headache waiting to happen.

Comment: @RetiredNinja The code works correctly with sanitizer turned on. So it does find the definition of the function...

Comment: @xkkdd I understand that, and if the sanitizer is making your program link correctly even though the command line is incorrect then it just creates a ticking time bomb since you're not going to ship with it enabled.